# VS2017 Debug my Shared Libraries on Linux Remote

Tags: linux, visual-studio, c++11, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution with few projects, in which there are 2 dynamic shared libraries.

When I build the solution on remote system linux based, all goes ok.

Then I try to debug the process. I launch the application directly on the board and try to attach to the process, but I'm not able to step into instructions of my shared libraries.

What's the problem? could it be because, as I read on the output panel, cannot the system load libraries' symbols..?? if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: UPDATES!!

It would seem to be a path problem.
By switching to the 'dlopen' function the relative path from the work directory, the function manages to load the shared library, but cannot load its symbols; passing the full path, under linux, '/home/user/...' there aren't problems.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, would you please post the comment as the answer?:)

Comment: thanks to everybody!

I finally solved it. Setting the full path ('/home/user/folder/subfolder/library.so' instead of '../../subfolder/library.so') for each file to load, the system works fine

Answer (score 1):

thanks to everybody!

I finally solved it.
Setting the full path

('/home/user/folder/subfolder/library.so' instead of '../../subfolder/library.so')

for each file to load, the system works fine. ;)

Comment: please mark it as the answer:) Thanks for sharing your solution here.