# Debugging Library Code with Visual Studio's Linux support

Tags: c++, gdb, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2017's integration to build and debug a CMake Linux application locally in the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

When running the application, Visual Studio uses an ssh connection to localhost to run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" ..` and `make`, then uses `gdbserver` to debug the application. This works fine for my application's own code, including breakpoints and line-by-line debugging.

This application links to a library file, `libhypro.so.17.09`, which is also part of a CMake project. This library is also built locally (stored in my Windows file system, built within Linux through the `/mnt/c/` mount, just as the main application) in debug mode. CMake did discover that dependency automatically.

I'm having trouble debugging my calls to this library. For example, if I break just before a call to library code and choose to *Step Into*, this is where I end up:

[image: screenshot from Visual Studio]

Note that

- the Call Stack has disappeared, showing `[Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]` instead,
- I'm inside an unhandled exception (which I'd expect to hit eventually, but certainly not immediately after a *Step Into*) and
- the *Modules* window indicates that no symbols are available.

In addition, I did set a breakpoint in the library's code, and Visual Studio (correctly) asserts that “the breakpoint will not currently be hit”. Also, Debug output prints `Loaded '/mnt/c/Users/felix/git/hypro/build/libhypro.so.17.09'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.`

I'm relatively certain that `libhypro.so.17.09` *does* include debug symbols as `nm -gC libhypro.so` prints *a lot*  of output.

My case appears to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44176131/926412) but I'm not specifying the library's path manually, it's discovered by CMake.

Why are `gdb` and, in turn, Visual Studio failing to debug the library's code?

Comment: Are you debugging in `gdbserver` mode? If so, try switching to `gdb` mode.

Comment: I do, and switching to `gdb` did help! Now, the symbols are shown as loaded, and when stepping into, Visual Studio asks me to locate the source file. Do you know why switching to `gdb` helps?

Comment: Also, would you mind posting this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are debugging in `gdbserver` mode, the default, try switching to `gdb` mode in the project properties / debugging page.

Basically, `gdbserver` mode is a nice idea that never quite delivered. Here's one  [discussion about it on the VCLinux GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/119). As you'll see, `gdb` will become the default debugging mode once they've fixed the problems with console applications.