# Could not launch gdb from Visual Studio for remote debugging Linux C++ project in Linux subsystem on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gdbserver

I am trying out [Targeting the Windows Subsystem for Linux from Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/). The project builds fine in Visual Studio:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: LinuxConsoleApp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Cleaning remote project directory
1>Validating architecture
1>Validating sources
1>Copying sources remotely to 'localhost'
1>Starting remote build
1>Compiling sources:
1>main.cpp
1>Linking objects
1>LinuxConsoleApp.vcxproj -> C:\...\LinuxConsoleApp\bin\x64\Debug\LinuxConsoleApp.out
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I can run it from the bash commandline prompt on Windows:

```
linux@windows-bash:/mnt/c/.../LinuxConsoleApp/bin/x64/Debug$ ./LinuxConsoleApp.out
hello from LinuxConsoleApp!
```

However, when I set a breakpoint to debug it from Visual Studio, I got error:

> "Could not launch gdb. gdb is missing from your system and needs to be
>   installed, please use your system's package manager to install it"

I did install gdbserver on the Linux subsystem on Windows. Does anyone know what else I need to make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start the SSH service and don't close the CMD windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, have you installed `gdb` on WSL? What does command `gdb --version` display?

Then recommend you debug in `gdb` mode, [see this topic for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890920/debugging-library-code-with-visual-studios-linux-support/46909617#46909617).

And, if you read the comments in the [original Visual Studio blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/) about using WSL, you will see that there are some issues around `ssh` which, if you follow the trail, will take you to [this fix](https://superuser.com/questions/1123552/how-to-ssh-into-wsl)

Comment: Yup, running 'sudo apt-get install gdb' to install gdb on WSL fixes it. Thank you for the nice reply!